# Python function to handle non existent parameters

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a slack bot in which I define the `/commands` to return a result like so:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def hello_there():
    if not is_request_valid(request):
        abort(400)

    return jsonify(
        response_type='in_channel',
        text='working',
    )
```

In the code snippet above the bot is waiting for a command that is `/test`.
I want to write a function that handles all other commands that are not existent in my code, so when I call a `/command` which is not existing the bot would return a text like 'Sorry this command is not existing'.

How could I write a function to handle this kind of behavior?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: [`@app.errorhandler(404)`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers)

Comment: how about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023864/flask-url-route-route-all-other-urls-to-some-function (which means `@app.errorhandler(404)`)

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question!